# Refresh JTable so data inserted is shown

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

I'm doing a project and I have two `JFrame` windows. first frame shows an empty table. A button below it would open the second frame where data should be entered. My problem is, when I click 'ok' in the second frame, the table on the first won't show the data inserted.

I tried `jframe.revalidate();` and `jframe.repaint()` as well as `table.revalidate();` and `table.repaint();` but it is not working.

Also, I'm using `DefaultTableModel` so I've also tried `model.fireTableDataChanged();` but still nothing.

```
//first jframe
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    viewTable();
}

Object[] newRow;

public NewJFrame(Object[] newRow){
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.newRow = newRow;
    addNewRow();
}

public void viewTable(){
    table.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    JTableHeader tablehead1 = table.getTableHeader();
    tablehead1.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    table.setRowHeight(30);

    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();        
    columnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(400);     //Name
    columnModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);    //Age
}

public void addNewRow(){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.addRow(newRow);
    System.out.println(newRow[0].toString() + newRow[1].toString()); //so i would know data is present
}

private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    form f = new form();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

```
//here's the second jframe
public form() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

private void OKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    Object[] input = { name.getText(), age.getText() };

    if(input.equals("")){
        System.out.println("empty");
    } else {
        NewJFrame n = new NewJFrame(input);
        n.revalidate();
        n.repaint();
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Comment: *"i have two jframes"* 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) `NewJFrame` Please use *meaningful* names for classes, methods and variables.

Comment: *"I tried .. but it is not working. Also, .. but still nothing."* The **only** thing that should be necessary is to add the data to the table model. If that doesn't work, the code is doing something ***very*** wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're passing the input data to a ***new*** NewJFrame and not to the existing one. The solution is to not do this, to pass it to the existing *and currently displayed* NewJFrame instance. How? Depends on your code. Note that the second "JFrame" should instead be a JDialog, likely a *modal* JDialog.